# manage all Bizspark subscription

Tags: azure, bizspark

I benefited from a  Bizspark subscription I created 5 other subscriptions my question how can i manage all resources in one account

**example**

I want to create VM1 in account 1 and other VM2 in account 2 after that i want to manage VM1 and VM2 in one account somthing like load balancing

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways to do this:
1. Share Acces from account 1 for the account 2
2. Add the subscription from account 1 to the tenant to the account 2